# Adobe Acrobat Browser Control Type Library 1.0 (Cannot add as reference)

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

I am trying to use the adobe com reference Adobe Acrobat Browser Control Type Library 1.0

When I try to add it it throws this error:

[image]

I have already tried re-installing Reader 11 and the .dll that is is complaining about is in the correct folder:

[image]

Not entirely sure what is going on ... am I missing other dependancies?
I have added:

[image]

but to no avail.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Your error dialog doesn't match your question title.  These are *separate* COM type libraries.  Your screenshot of your References shows that you did in fact added a reference to "Adobe Acrobat x.x Browser Control Type Library".  The error message is for another one, "Adobe Reader File Preview Type Library".  It produces a reference named FileViewLib when successful.

Comment: Thanks Hans ... you were spot on. I have the correct ref now. I should take more breaks!